# Text ellipsis not working when icon beside it in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

recently I am moving on the Flutter , I am making one list but stuck with Overflow error even ellipsis is there.

My requirement is **Icon must be stick with text** so I **cant use expanded**.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `Text` widget with `Expanded` or `Flexible` because over only works when it's parent has `Expanded` or `Flexible` .

or try this.

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: const [
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  ///your text here
                  'Yearly',
                  style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Icon(Icons.timer),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Text('2', style: FontStyleUtility.blackInter18W600)
      ],
    )
```

Comment: yes but if i wrap textview with expanded ,  icon cant stick beside it

Comment: check updated code.

Comment: great working like charm.  thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text widget with the `SizedBox()` or `Flexible()` and give it a width with the max size of your choice

```
...
Flexible(
   child: Text(
...
   ),
...
```

Or

```
...
SizedBox(
   width: 180,
   child: Text(
...
   ),
...
```

Comment: but i dont want static width  i want to expand it till the right side ,

Comment: Then it won't work cause `TextOverflow.ellipsis` works with a given constraint or use `Flexible()`

Comment: not working bro

Answer (score -1):

Try Wrapping the Text in a Container and provide the width you want then it will work.